# C Max of Four Wrong Answer

Tags: c

I just started learning programming and i couldnt find whats wrong with my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (a > b && a > c && a > d) {
        printf("%d",a);
    }
    if (b > a && b > c && b > d) {
        printf("%d",b);
    }
    if (c > a && c > b && c > d) {
        printf("%d",c);
    }
    if (d > a && d > b && d > c) {
        printf("%d",d);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);
    
   return 0;
}
```

I try to input 3 4 5 6 but the output is 60

Comment: `60` in your case is actually `6` printed by one of `printf`s in the function immediately followed by `0` printed by `main()`. `max_of_four` always returns `0` as the result, hence the behavior.

Comment: It prints `6` (the highest) and then `0` (he function's return value). I suggest putting a space or a newline after each output, so they don't all run into each other.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `return 0;` inside of `max_of_four`, exactly what do you think that means? Where the code says `printf("%d", ans);`, what do you think this will do, and why should it do that? How many times should `printf` get called in order to display the result of the calculation? If you try carefully tracing through the logic of the program, step by step, how many times does it get called?

Comment: Note that a simpler implementation would be to repeatedly use "max of two"  `return max(max(a, b), max(c, d))`. Building "higher level" functions from smaller components is an important skill to learn.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are confusing `print` and `return`.
2. Your are printing twice
3. If you want to print numbers on different lines, you have to add a `\n` in the printing. Or spaces, if you just want them separated by spaces. But just printing numbers with plain `printf("%d",number1); ...; printf("%d",number2);` will print the two numbers digts without any separation. Here `printf("%d",6);printf("%d",0);` prints `60`.

Your `max_of_four` function prints its result (which is 6), but returns 0.

Then the main function prints the value of `max_of_four(...)`, which is 0 (because it returned 0).
So, unsurprisingly, what is printed is 6 then 0, that is 60.

`max_of_four` should not print anything, since you meant it as a function that returns a result. Anyway, that would be printing the result twice, even if it worked.
It should just return the result. And then, it is up to the caller (main function) to print the result if it wishes.

So, long story short

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (a > b && a > c && a > d) {
        return a;
    }
    if (b > a && b > c && b > d) {
        return b;
    }
    if (c > a && c > b && c > d) {
        return c;
    }
    if (d > a && d > b && d > c) {
        return d;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d\n", ans);
    
   return 0;
}
```

That is to answer to what bothers you in your example. But there are other problems in your code.

For example, what happens if two of the numbers are equal? For example, if input is `4 5 5 2`

Your function would return 0, not 5 in such case. But, since you are learning, I let you think about how to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

> but the output is 60

More specifically, the output is `6` *and then* `0`.  The `6` is output here:

```
printf("%d",d);
```

And the `0` is output here:

```
printf("%d", ans);
```

Since the `max_of_four` function *always returns 0* then there's really no need to capture and output that value.  You can remove the second output:

```
int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

(At which point the `max_of_four` function doesn't need to return anything at all, of course.)

---

Alternatively, if you want the `max_of_four` function to return the max value, then *return* it instead of *printing* it:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (a > b && a > c && a > d) {
        return a;
    }
    if (b > a && b > c && b > d) {
        return b;
    }
    if (c > a && c > b && c > d) {
        return c;
    }
    if (d > a && d > b && d > c) {
        return d;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `max_of_four(1,1,1,1)` is returning `0`. Function does not work. Also `(5,5,2,1)`  or (5,5,5,1));

Comment: This is the right answer (notwithstanding that the function's logic doesn't handle ties), but the question should not be answered as it either is a typo (if asked by someone with any real experience) or reflects a failure to debug and isolate the problem for a proper MRE (if asked by a complete beginner, as appears to be the case). Yes, that does mean that questions like this effectively cannot be asked properly by people who would actually have them. Experts of the [c] tag should try to notice patterns in beginner questions and preempt the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I would implement it this way:

```
int max_of_two(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b; 
}

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return max_of_two(max_of_two(max_of_two(a,b), c), d);
}
```

It will also generate much better code: https://godbolt.org/z/GsTPsbGWa

Or for any number of parameters (except  no parameters):

```
int max_of_two(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b; 
}

int max_of_many(size_t size, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    int max;

    va_start(va, size);
    max = va_arg(va, int);
    size -= 1;
    while(size--)
    {
        max = max_of_two(max, va_arg(va, int));
    }
    va_end(va);
    return max;
}
```

And usage

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", max_of_many(1, 5));
    printf("%d\n", max_of_many(2, 5, 6));
    printf("%d\n", max_of_many(3, 5, 6, 7));
    printf("%d\n", max_of_many(4, 5, 6 ,7, 8));
    printf("%d\n", max_of_many(5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
}
```

Comment: Any comment silent downvoter? Or is it a revenge one?

Comment: a) wasn't me b) all the answers got one downvote c) probably for answering a question which the voter perceived as a bad question d) my reason to almost downvote is the "I would implement this way" without any attempt to help OP with understanding their unexpected output or guessing which misunderstanding might have caused it.

Comment: Wasn’t me either.  It looks like there’s a lot of contention on this question regarding how it should be answered or if it should be answered at all.  I disagree with some of the opinions expressed in that regard.  Ultimately all we can do is what we think is in keeping with the community standards and purpose and hope for the best.  Sometimes the community responds in disappointing ways.  It is still just the internet after all.